# Not able to create lightningQuickAction in packaging org

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

I have a lightning component implementing force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader which is working fine in my dev org. When I deploy this to the packaging org and try to create a quick action, its not available in the list of lightning components.

I removed the entire code from the component except this:

```
<aura:component access="global" controller="ScenarioCtlr" implements="force:lightningQuickAction" >

</aura:component>
```

And created a quick action successfully. 
Put my code back in the lightning component and edit the quick action. Its showing me the component id rather than the name of component. When I save, throw me below error.

[image: Error: You can only create Lightning Component Quick Actions for Component Bundles containing a component that implements force:lightningQuickAction and has no required attributes without a default value.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to fix this issue. My lightning component has 2 attributes of type wrapper. My wrapper class was an inner class and attribute type I was passing value like this:

I moved my wrapper class from outer class and created the wrapper class as an outer class and modified the aura:attribute like this:

And it started working. Hope this help others.

Answer (score 0):

@Raghvendra, this seems to be known issue, can you please try the workaround suggested on https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ei4BQAQ and let us know if it works for you.